# How to write an interface for ffplay and let it react to the keyboard event

Tags: c++, qt

I want to write an interface for ffplay using QProcess.
I just launch the ffplay.exe using QProcess, but how can I send keyboard envent to ffplay ?
I use write method in QProcess, but it doesn't make any sense. Is there a way that I could send message to ffplay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ffplay changes from version to version, but in the code I'm looking at I don't see any IPC code and events are received from the GUI which is developed in SDL. So you can use that way or you can change the event_loop() function in ffplay.c to get events from stdin for instance, and you use the write() method of QProcess to send the events.

You could also simply wrap ffplay code in your own class removing the main() and the event_loop() function.